# How to uncheck ToggleButton from programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This is my code

```
private void buttonClickone(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (WhichV == -1) {
        ShowMessage(PleaseSelectXXX);
        return;
    }

    ButtonClick(1);
    BeginOPHandler(Ep, null);
}
```

My logic here is, if the condition of the if-statement is met, I want to uncheck the toggle button but not perform the `BeginOPHandler(Ep, null)` operation.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement has also an `else` case

```
if (condition met) {
    uncheck the toggle button 
} else {
    ButtonClick(1);   
    BeginOPHandler(Ep, null);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
   buttonName.IsChecked = false
```

That should uncheck the button.